# Adobe Lightroom Slow after Installing Develop Presets

Tags: macintosh, lightroom-5

After installing all VSCO Film Presets on 2 different Macs on Mac OS Mavericks(using Lr 5.4), I've noticed constant hangs and some slowdowns when using it. 
Prior to installation, software was pretty quick. Does anybody have the same issue and knows the solution? I didn't find anything useful searching on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you installed on 2 different Macs. Do they both have the slowness problem?

Two possible causes:

- The installation didn't go well and some files were incorrectly installed. When LR tries to load them, internal failures happen, and the whole process becomes slower. Can you open/use every single preset?
- You installed too many presets. The more presets you have the slower to open the Develop module.

My advice: Uninstall/Delete the new presets; Install again; Delete the ones you don't like; Optimize Catalog.

Good luck.

Comment: Well, I guess there are just too many presets installed. When disabled, Lr is blazing fast again :/ 
What I'm doing is: When scrolling through my library, I let them disabled, and when editing, enable them again. It works.
Thanks!